# find the minimum of the sum of two weighted functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both have a global minimum, and we take the weighted sum of them like the following:

$$ w \cdot f(x) + (1-w)  \cdot g(x)$$

Will this also be convex? And since this is a linear combination, does it suffice to say that the minimum is

$$ w \cdot f_{min} +(1-w) \cdot g_{min}$$

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ and $g$ are both convex? This is not a consequence of what you've said.

Comment: Yes I'm assuming $f$ and $g$ are convex.

Comment: I think your conjectured formula for the minimum will be valid only when $f$ and $g$ attain their minimum at the same $x$ value.

Comment: can we extract some relationship between $f_{min}$ and $g_{min}$ if they are not the same?

Comment: Unstated, but quite important, is the fact that $0\leq w \leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are convex then the sum of convex function is convex, hence yes, it is convex.

However, let $f(x)=2x^2$ and $g(x) = (x-1)^2$

then $\frac12f(x) + \frac12g(x)=x^2+\frac12(x-1)^2$

the minimal pont occurs when $2x+(x-1)=0$

$$x=\frac13$$

and the corresponding value is $\frac19+\frac12\cdot \frac49 >0$